# Is there an inverse operation to Python inspect.getcallargs in the standard library?

Tags: python

Is there a way to get back from a return value from `inspect.getcallargs(func)` to a `*args, **kw` pair that can actually be used to call the `func`?

Use case: say I am writing a decorator, and I want to change a particular argument of a function by name.  Here's the beginning of some code to do this:

```
@fix_x
def a(x):
    print x

@fix_x
def b(**q):
    print q['x']

def fix_x(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        callargs = inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kw)
        if 'x' in callargs:
            callargs['x'] += 5
        elif 'x' in callargs[argspec.keywords]:
            callargs[argspec.keywords]['x'] += 5
        # ...and now I'd like a simple way to call func with callargs...?
```

(I'm actually doing something more elaborate with the callargs between building them and wanting to make a call with them, but this should give an idea of what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't currently a good way to do this, however it is in the works for Python 3.3!

See [PEP 362 -- Function Signature Object](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) for how this new feature will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own code to (more or less) do this.  It is in `ArgSpec.make_call_args` in https://github.com/codemage/wmpy

The semantics are slightly different; namely, it will still just shunt any unknown args to **kw rather than accepting a separate entry dict named after the **kw parameter, but that is easy enough to change if I ever need to.

With a little bit of effort, this could probably be turned into a fairly complete 'backport' (in quotes since it obviously wouldn't share code) of [PEP 362](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) to Python 2.7.  It doesn't do keyword-only params, but those don't exist in 2.x anyway so that wouldn't affect API completeness, and the inspect module provides all the other nontrivial machinery.